# UIAlertController example try out, Show error and not sure how to fix it

Tags: swift, xcode7

```
class alert {
func msg(message: String, title: String = "")
{
    let alertView = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)

    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .Default, handler: nil))

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

I found this code in stackoverflow, and tried on Xcode 7. But it show error on presentviewcontroller, error read "Cannot call value of non-function type 'UIViewController'?". did I typed something incorrect?

thanks

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: I put your code on  a single view controller's `viewDidload` method, which work fine.